# Will frequent polling overload the server? If so, what's the best way of implementing live updates?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Well I dont know which is the most efficient way to do. Could someone help me in finding out  a better algorithm.

okay let us take some example like facebook when user posts a post, it will be updated to his friend without any page refresh and we know its by ajax request . But how can we know that some one has posted a new thing? may be like putting a timer for every 2 seconds and sending an ajax request for some table and checking if some user posted something.right? but is there a way to do without setting a timer because performing the operation for every 2 seconds may cause severe server issue i think so ? just wanna know if there is a better way instead of setting a timer?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe websockets? http://www.davesite.com/html5-code-tutorials/html5_interactive_intro_html_5/websockets/

Comment: @niko i was thinking the same when it comes to using ajax based on-live updates and yet couldn't find any other solutions. i don't think there can be a solution without establishing connection with server. but in worst case scenario you can increase time interval from 2 to 4 or more

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently what Facebook and Google employ, is a technique called [long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling).

It's a simple system whereby the client makes an AJAX request to the server. The server takes the request and checks to see if it has the data the request needs. If not, the request is left open but deferred by the server. The second the server has the data, the request is handled and returned to the client.

If you open up facebook, you'll see requests being posted to Facebook which take around 55 seconds to complete. Same goes for Gmail and a few other web applications that seem to have some kind of push system.

Here's a simple example of how these requests might be handled:

1. Client:

   - Initial AJAX request which has the `timestamp 0`
2. Server:

   - Compare request with `timestamp 0` by checking the timestamp of the data on the server. Lets say the data on the server has the `timestamp 234`.
   - The client stamp is different from the current stamp on the server data so we return with the new data.
3. Client:

   - Client gets the data and immediately posts a new AJAX request with `timestamp 234`.
   - Then we process the new data and update the web page appropriately.
4. Server:

   - Compares request with `timestamp 234` with the current stamp of the data on the server.
   - The stamp values are the same so we go to sleep.
   - Server data is update and stamp value is now `timestamp 235`.
   - Sleeping requests are woken up and returned with update value.

You can read a more [in-depth](http://nadirmuzaffar.blogspot.com/2013/03/polling-long-polling-comet-server-side.html) explanation of more modern mechanisms for live updates.

Comment: It's simple on the client side, but in many web frameworks where you just write the code to handle the single request it's not trivial to do it efficiently.

Comment: There's definitely synchronization and usually a degree of caching involved, but its definitely not the most difficult synchronization problem to be proposed. It's challenging yet simple enough to be fun. Obviously creating a model as efficient as Facebook's or Google's is not the same.

Comment: In many web frameworks where you are just required to write a function that given a request provides a reply it's just impossible to "sleep". In other frameworks you can use standard sleep techniques where one thread per pending request is needed, and this is much less efficient than what is needed. To handle long polling efficiently on server side (i.e. without a thread per pending request) is clearly possible and even fun to do... but "simple" is not the word I'd use.

Comment: This answer is most right.     

Hold onto the clients request, and when there is new data, send it. The client sends a request back immediately for the server can hold onto until the next update is available, or they just request it again later.

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents but I have previously solved a similar problem by having 2 webservices. Basically one with a method along the lines of `HaveNewData()` and another `GetData()` (In my case I had a number of webservices I wanted to call).

So basically call `HaveNewData()` on a regular basis (I think in any case every 2 seconds is a bad design and unnecessary) and return a simple 0 or 1 for this method (minimal data). If `HaveNewData()` returns 1 then make your expensive webservice call. Alternatively you could also just return a null value in the primary webservice when no new data is available and in my experience this scales at least "pretty" reasonably.

Answer (score 0):

Long polling is a great technique but as with any solution the efficacy depends on many variables including hardware setup and hence there are no absolute solutions.

Please be aware that Long polling you are keeping the connection alive which **may** cause performance issues with many clients.

You solution should take into account :-

1. Does it need to be almost realtime (for example a stockticker)
2. How often the ajax data/output changes (chat vs new comment)
3. How often does the event that causes changes to ajax data/output triggers. This will dictate how the cache is generated.

You should be a frugal when it comes to ajax. Request & response should be done on a need basis. The success of a ajax implementation will be incomplete without a well thought out caching solution which is more event based rather than request based.

Below is a simplified version of one of the techniques we found useful in a project:-

1. Every Ajax poll request that is made will contain **output_hash** which is the digest of the data returned by the server previously.
2. Server checks this **output_hash** against the recent hash of the output it will have generated, from data source preferably stored in cache.
3. If it is different then it will serve the new content along with new **output_hash**. Else a small response / Not modified to indicate there is no new content.

In our solution we also did dynamic calculation of the interval of the next poll. Keeping the interval dynamic allows the server to control the request. For example let's assume most comments / answers happen in the first 1 hour, beyond that there is no point having the interval time as 1 sec, so the server can increase that to 2,3 or even 5 sec dynamically as the time increases, rather than hard coding the interval as 2 sec. Similarly the interval time can be decreased if there is flurry of activity in an old post.

We also checked for idle clients and other things.